# Discourage questions about Stack Overflow Documentation being posted here

Tags: discussion, migration, meta, documentation-beta

Since the [public beta release](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/07/introducing-stack-overflow-documentation-beta/?cb=1) of Stack Overflow Documentation, [a](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328853/what-is-the-approval-procedure-of-documentation) [lot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328880/look-for-published-and-requested-topics-while-creating-a-new-topic) [of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328764/documentation-beta-consensus-how-to-give-an-example) [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328564/some-feedback-on-the-design-of-the-documentation-system) [about](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328438/upstreaming-content-on-stack-overflow-documentation) it have been posted here and migrated to Meta Stack Overflow (where they belong) subsequently.

I have already proposed a tag wiki excerpt for [documentation-beta](/questions/tagged/documentation-beta), pointing users in the right direction, but there may be other things we can do. Can Documentation be added as an exception to the on-topic list in the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? Or do we just wait until the storm is over, and enjoy the flagging / close-voting spree in the meantime?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Or do we just wait until the storm is over, and enjoy the flagging / close-voting spree in the meantime?

Yes.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't have much use to add it to the help center. Users simply won't read it. Sometimes a site-wide banner could help, but we have seen in the past that doesn't help much either.

So yes, we should just wait until this is over. Keep in mind sometimes questions could even be on-topic here if the question is about the use of the Documentation feature network-wide.

Comment: Network-wide use is more of a distant future hope, but it would be nice to have a more coherent policy on MSE acceptability of features that are *currently* SO-specific but will hopefully eventually move out to other sites (Triage, Jobs, Documentation).

Comment: @NathanTuggy. That would make a decent new MSE question in its own right. \*hint hint\*